Spark+Hive insertion speed degration
Question about Spark+Hive insertion speed degration
Hi, I'm new to using Spark+Hive with Python.
Although partitions are used, the insertion speed degrades as the table grows.
I have done some experiments on two duplicated VMs with different numbers of rows (143257162 and 585562 rows).
There are no performance differences when inserting into a new table, but it is 4~5 times slower when inserting into a new partition (a new date).
Is this normal, or have I done something wrong? Thanks.
Spark: 3.1.3
Hadoop: 3.2
Hive: 3.1.2
My table is created and inserted with this piece of code.
df.repartition(1, *part_list).write.option(
        "maxRecordsPerFile", max_records
    ).partitionBy(*part_list).mode(mode).format("orc").saveAsTable(tbl)

I've tried to set hive autogather to false, but it seems no improvement

It is caused by hive 3.1.2 metastore, updating hive to 3.1.3 solves the problem perfectly.
